# Use dot notation with angular number filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, locale

I have an input field. The user enters a number. I need this number to be formatted correctly with dots representing the thousands (not the decimals)
user input : 5600 -> becomes 5.600 (five thousand six hundred)
user input: 56000 -> becomes 56.000
etc

I need the number to be formatted correctly INSIDE the input field.

I have a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/El4a/KPeBD/1059/

This fiddle works perfectly BUT it uses the number filter from angular thus it formats the numbers with a comma-notation. I however need a dot-notation.

So I tried replacing the comma manually by a dot.

```
 var listener = function() {

            var value = $element.val().replace(/,/g, '') //delete all notations

            var x = $element.val($filter('number')(value, 0)) //filter
            $element.val(x).replace(/,/g, '.') //replace comma by dot
        }
```

This didn't work.

I then tried to use a locale cdn (as can be seen in the linked fiddle).
This seemed to be the solution at first creating :

[image: dot-notation]

But when the next 0 is added it flips and does :

[image: nope]

I figured I also had to change the following line

```
var value = $element.val().replace(/,/g, '')
```

to

```
var value = $element.val().replace(/./g, '')
```

but then the input field is completely unusable.

Hope someone has a solution for me!

Comment: Just removed var value = $element.val().replace(/,/g, '') and it seems to display what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldt3g201/

Comment: It has to format this inside the input field. When I check your fiddle, it gives me no format inside the field, only outside it.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the directive as it's not that much helpful on filtering the number.

we can use `angular filter ($filter)` for the same. changed the code into

```
myApp.filter('number', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
return function (input, symbol, fraction) {
  if (input) {
    var decimal = input.toString().split('.')[1],
      value = input.toString().split('.')[0],
      filtered = value.replace(/(?=(\d\d\d)$)/g, ".");
    return (decimal) ? (fraction > 0 ? filtered + '.' + decimal.slice(0, fraction) : filtered) :  filtered;
  } else {
    return 0
  }
}
}])
```

sorry I've removed the entire directive section and updated the jsFiddle.

Here is the updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KPeBD/1055/)

Comment: No sorry I think you misunderstood. I will edit my question. In your fiddle, the input field displays for example 650000000.... without ever using a .

Answer (score 0):

OMG I finally found it...

I forgot to escape the goddamn . char:

so changing

```
var value = $element.val().replace(/./g, '')
```

to

```
var value = $element.val().replace(/\./g, '')
```

made it work

48hours well spent...